# Wheel and tire clearance to trailer chassis

Tags: tires, trailer

I have a trailer with a rubber-torsion axle (axle is fixed to chassis, hubs are mounted to swing arms that are embedded in the ends of the rubber-filled tube axle).  Since the swing arms move only in the vertical plane, and cannot move side-to-side, I assume I can fit wheels/tires that have minimal clearance from the trailer chassis. What is a reasonable minimum clearance between the inner side of the wheel/tire assembly and the nearest part of the trailer chassis?

Answer (score 1):

This would depend a great deal on the load carried and the tyre pressure.
The tyres will Flex and bulge somewhat and can fail if allowed to rub against the chassis.
My trailer has a couple of inches clearance.